# C# AOP Method Interception on child method calls?

Tags: c#, aop, aspects

My AOP (C#) implementation always intercepts the first (public) method call but not subsequent methods called within the first intercepted method, is this a limitation with ContextBoundObject AOP implementations or am I doing it wrong?

```
[InterceptMe]
public void MethodOne()
{
    MethodTwo();
}

[InterceptMe]
public void MethodTwo() 
{ 
   //not intecepted from MethodOne Call 
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, context bound object interception only works for intercepting calls at a context boundary. Since methodtwo lies within the same context as methodone, it does not cross a boundary and will not be intercepted.